# Why react receives updates for redux state asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a little problem in my React/Redux application.

When I dispatch an action to change my redux state, React component receives the changed state asynchronously. But I want to handle the changes synchronously.

The code is here:

```
// Component
class App extends React.Component {
  handleButtonChange = e => {
    this.props.change("Hello World");
    console.log(this.props.title);   // print old value
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.props.title); // print new value
    }, 100);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonChange}>
          Change the title
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  title: state.title
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  change: title => dispatch(change(title))
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Any ideas?

The full example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxjkvvk3pl

Comment: What is your goal with those logs? Do you want to ensure that this.props.title is the new value before logging?

Comment: it's not asynchronous. The only asynchronous part of the code is the setTimeout. The code is code sndbox is different to the code here (slightly). but there is no asynchronous code here (except for the setTimeout). please someone correct me if I am wrong. p.s. when i click the button in code sandbox it appears to all happen synchronously.

Comment: Carwyn, you are right. Right after `this.props.change("Hello World");` row I want to use the new value of title (the "Hello World"). But console.log will display the old value "Hello"

Comment: Joey, if I don't use setTimeout I can't use the new value of `this.props.title` because it stays unchanged (the value is 'Hello')

Comment: @MikhailLipilin you can use the new value of `this.props.title` in the `componentDidUpdate()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `connect()` method, it does not modify the component class passed to it; instead, it returns a new, connected component class for you to use.

The `mapStateToProps()` function is called any time the connector component needs to compute new props, as a result of a store state change.

Reference: [react-redux api](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

---

When you dispatch an action:

```
 this.props.change("Hello World");
 console.log(this.props.title);
```

Which will make the store state change, as a result, the `mapStateToProps()` function will be invoked and the `connect()` function will get the current component and return for you a new component with the updated `props`.

The `console.log(this.props.title)` is executed with the value of the property title of the **old** props object of the **old** component.

---

I put some lifecycle hooks in your codes to see what actually happened:

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { change } from "./actions";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("contructor(): " + this.props.title);
  }
  handleButtonChange = e => {
    this.props.change("Hello World");
    console.log("handleButtonChange(): " + this.props.title);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount(): " + this.props.title);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    if (this.props.title !== prevProps.title) {
      console.log("componentDidUpdate(): " + this.props.title);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("componentWillUnmount(): " + this.props.title);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render(): " + this.props.title);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonChange}>Change the title</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  title: state.title
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  change: title => dispatch(change(title))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

---

And the results after clicking *four* times on the button are:

[image]

---

Therefore, in case you want to use the new computed props for the first time, it's updated, you should do it in the `componentDidUpdate()`

However, I also see that you want to use the new `props` directly after dispatching an action:

```js
this.props.change("Hello World");
// stop here, creating a new component, merging props, then executing the next line
console.log(this.props.title);
```

I think that's somehow impossible.

The rework demo:  https://codesandbox.io/s/wol55qqx0k

Comment: if it's not asynchronous, Why setTimeout() returns a new value? Why the system can't wait till new props passing....