# why I am not getting updated props value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

could you please tell me why not getting updated props value in react.

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-basic-counter-1e8gdh?file=shared/components/NavBar.js

In my example I have a button `-` .on click it decrement the value. I dispatch the action value is `decremented` but I am not getting `updated value`

```
 handle=()=>{
    this.props.decrement();
    this.getCount();
  }

  getCount=()=>{
    const {counter}= this.props;
    console.log(counter);
  }
```

see my **console.log**

expected output is **`-1`**

current output is `0`

why? It is showing output when I click on `-` button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is at the point of printing the value in the console the props are not updated. When the props are updated the react component re-renders and display the counter value. To check that you can use a `setTimeout`.

```
  handle=()=>{
    this.props.decrement();
    setTimeout(this.getCount,10)
  }
```

if you want to console log the value you can you the life cycle. 
you can use componentDidUpdate

```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.counter !== prevProps.counter) {
      console.log(this.props.counter);
    }
  }
```

or componentWillReceiveProps (for react version < 16)

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if( newProps.counter != this.props.counter ) {
    console.log(newProps.counter);
  }
}
```

or else getDerivedStateFromProps (react version 16 +)

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.counter !== prevState.counter ) {
     console.log(nextProps.counter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I wanted to publish my answer. But you it made first

Comment: `prevState.counter` is not defined

Comment: there is no `counter` in state

Comment: @user944513 what life cycle did you use? according to your example you should use componentWillReceiveProps()

Comment: @TRomesh could you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778691/why-react-receives-updates-for-redux-state-asynchronously) and update your answer

Comment: how ? can you please tell me how ?

Comment: @user944513 i have updated my answer you can use componentDidUpdate() life cycle for this too